# How exactly user count limitation works on TFS Express?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

TFS Express is limited to 5 users. I can't figure out, how this limitation works exactly and how do I manage users who could work with it.

Is it counts all users in all groups configured in TFS? Or per project? Does administrator account counts (it absolutely can work with all features as a developer). If yes, could I completely change TFS administrator later to some other user who will actually work with TFS as a developer?

Same question with TFS Online. When adding Live IDs to a group, if I'm correct, I could add more than 5 users. How exactly it will restrict their work once user count become more than 5? Does repository owner counts so that I can actually work with only 4 other users, not 5?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it limits the total amount of users across all groups (more specifically I believe it has a TFS Valid Users group or something like that).  So 5 users total across the entire TFS or VSO instance.